# dynamically set selectedIndex of asp:dropdown

Tags: c#

I am having text which is to be shown selected like "selected", "unselected"

dynamically I wanted to set "selected" like

```
dropdown.selectedIndex = dropdown.Items.FindByText("selected");
```

how to set? please guide

Comment: could i able do it in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there

```
dropdown.Items.FindByText("selected").Selected = true;
```

**EDIT**

To achieve this via javascript you will have to loop through the `option` elements of the dropdown. something like this

```
function setIndexByText() 
{
   drp = document.myform.selectcontrol; //this would be your dropdown
   str = "selected";
   for (indx=0; indx < drp.options.length; indx++) 
   {
       if (drp.options[indx].text == str) 
       {
          drp.selectedIndex = indx;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: could i able to do it in javascript?